# Custom Functions in C++ Template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, vivado-hls

If I am using a C++ class with a template parameter of an int like:

```
template<int width> class ap_uint { ... }
```

then I understand that I can create specific definitions from this type of certain widths like:

```
typedef ap_uint<72> data_t;
```

However, if I wanted to say define a constant and pass that in, what are my options (other than define)? Say something like this:

```
#define WIDTH 72
typedef ap_uint<WIDTH> data_t;
typedef ap_uint<WIDTH / 8> mask_t; // Does this even work?
```

Further would it be possible to define a function or use an existing one in the template parameter selection? Something like this:

```
#define SIZE 1024
typedef ap_uint<ceil(log(SIZE, 2))> addr_t;
```

I am fine having to write the functions myself, if that is even possible.

Comment: The alternaitve to #define are `constexpr` and other template calculations.

Comment: Yep, that's possible and called template meta-programming (there are some examples https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Templates/Template_Meta-Programming)

Comment: Since `ap_uint` takes an `int` as a parameter, [yes](http://cpp.sh/7n2rp). There should be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some observations, in no particular order.

(1) you tagged C++11, so not only `typedef` but (better, IMHO) also `using`

```
using data_t = ap_uint<72>;
```

(2) you can also "templatize" `using`

```
template <int I>
using data_t = ap_uint<I+3>;
```

(3) "does this even work?"

```
#define WIDTH 72    
typedef ap_uint<WIDTH / 8> mask_t;
```

Works.

But, given that you tagged C++11, I suggest to avoid `#define` and use a `constexpr` constant instead

```
constexpr auto WIDTH = 72;

using mask_t = ap_uint<WIDTH / 8>;
```

(4) "would it be possible to define a function or use an existing one in the template parameter selection"

Pre C++11 the answer was: no.

But you tagged C++11 so the answer is: yes, but the function must be a `constexpr` one

Example

```
constexpr int foo (int a)
 { return a+3; }

constexpt int bar = 42;

using data_t = ap_uint<foo(bar)>; // compile: foo(bar) is a constant expression

int baz = 42;

using data_t2 = ap_uint<foo(baz)>; // compilation error! baz isn't a constant 
                                   // expression so foo(baz) isn't
```

(5) `std::ceil()` and `std::log()` aren't `constexpr` so

```
#define SIZE 1024
typedef ap_uint<ceil(log(SIZE, 2))> addr_t;
```

doesn't compile

(6) "I am fine having to write the functions myself, if that is even possible."

Starting from C++11 it's possible (see point (4) for an example).

Unfortunately, only starting from C++14 it's possible to write complex `constexpr` functions.

In C++11, a `constexpr` function can almost contains only (simplifying a little) a `return` instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Template arguments must be constant expressions. So your options include `#define`, `enum`, `const int` and `constexpr int` and expressions/functions that yield constant expressions (specifically `constexpr` functions). `constexpr int` is the modern C++ way of doing it.

`WIDTH / 8` does work.

In essence it must be a compile-time constant

Comment: Constexpr functions were exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr